# Delete log files programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a static folder path where I save log files. My question is, instead of deleting manually, how do I delete them programmatically at a regular interval.

I would prefer c# code.

Comment: We're not really a code-writing service - what have you tried so far, and what problems have you found with your approach? Have a look at "[*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" for some tips.

Answer (score 4):

```
File.Delete(@"some_path_to_file");
```

Edit : If you want to go over all files in directory, you can use something like

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("your static folder path");
foreach (FileInfo f in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            File.Delete(f.FullName);                  
        }
```

And if you need to do it 'at a regular interval' you could utilize the [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) scheduler to invoke this job. It's quite easy to set up.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the previous answers this is what I came up with for my needs (large IIS log files were driving me crazy!):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LogFileDeleter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\inetpub\\logs\\logfiles\\w3svc1");
            DateTime testDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5);
            foreach (FileInfo f in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                DateTime fileAge = f.LastWriteTime;
                if (fileAge < testDate) {
                    Console.WriteLine("File " + f.Name + " is older than today, deleted...");
                    File.Delete(f.FullName);
                }
                //Console.ReadLine(); //Pause -- only needed in testing.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Should be obvious but it only deletes files over 5 days old and only in the W3SVC1 directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    if(File.Exists(filePath))
    {
         File.Delete(filePath);
    }
}
catch{}
```